# Как центрировать изображение в PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, form

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]На работе один элемент `SplitContainer`.  В нем два `Picturebox-а` - `pic1` и `pic2`. Как сделать чтобы элементы `pic1` и `pic2` были с отступами от `SplitContainer`. Проблема в том что у `pic1` и `pic2` стоят свойства  `Dock-Fill`. Хотелось бы чтобы картинка была с отступом от `PictureBox`. 
Если сделать Padding 30;30;30;30 то получается. Т.е. почему то праый padding не работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать вместа свойства `Image` свойство `BackgroundImage` и в паре с ним:

```
pic1.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center;
```

Более того, можно вообще выкинуть `PictureBox`ы и задать свойства `BackgroundImage` и `BackgroundImageLayout` непосредственно панелям `SplitContainer`а.

---

Чтобы установить отступы, нужно задать свойство `Padding` у `SplitterPanel`. Тогда появится промежуток между бордюром `PictureBox`а и `SplitterPanel`ью.

Comment: А как сделать отступы?

Comment: @Radzhab654654 - Не совсем понятно, какие отступы имеются в виду. Попробуйте изменить Padding. А вообще, если изображение меньше панели, то отступы будут сами по себе.